# How to know my website is available all over the world?

Tags: web

I have a website at e.g. http://example.com

This website is not available in China! I searched a lot but can not find the reason. My website is available elsewhere but not in china. Why?

How can I test my website availability for different countries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Suddenly find the best solution. You can use this website:

```
 host-tracker.com
```

Just type your website and it loads it using lots of servers all over world and reports the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a proxy hosted in the desired country to browse as if you were there. 
https://www.google.es/search?q=proxy+china&oq=proxy+china